# Prisma client type system creates strong coupling with service methods

Tags: nestjs, prisma

I am using `prisma` ORM with `nestjs` and it is awesome. Can you please help me understand how can I separate my database layer from my service methods since results produced by prisma client queries are of types generated by prisma client itself ( so i wont be having those types when i shift to lets say typeorm ). how can i prevent such coupling of my service methods returning results of types generated by prisma client and not my custom entities. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: Not sure if I understood correctly, but maybe you can just declare the return type of your service methods by yourself?

Comment: yeah, i just need an example of how people use prisma client generated types and still able to change the database implementation details later on without have to worry about their service methods were somehow tied to prisma generated types.  I want to make them irrelevant when it comes to applicaiton's service layer

Comment: I think you can't. If you decide to use prisma generated types, then coupling is already made.

Answer (score 2):

The generated `@prisma/client` library is responsible for generating both the types as well as the custom entity classes. As a result, if you replace Prisma you end up losing both.

Here are two possible workarounds that can decouple the types of your service methods from the Prisma ORM.

##### Workaround 1: Generate types indepedently of Prisma

With this approach you can get rid of Prisma altogether in the future by *manually defining* the types for your functions. You can use the types generated by Prisma as reference (or just copy paste them directly). Let me show you an example.

Imagine this is your Prisma Schema.

```
model Post {
  id        Int      @default(autoincrement()) @id
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
  title     String   @db.VarChar(255)
  author    User     @relation(fields: [authorId], references: [id])
  authorId  Int
}


model User {
  id      Int      @default(autoincrement()) @id
  name    String?
  posts   Post[]
}
```

You could define a `getUserWithPosts` function as follows:

```js
// Copied over from '@prisma/client'. Modify as necessary.
type User = {
    id: number
    name: string | null     
}

// Copied over from '@prisma/client'. Modify as necessary.
type Post = {
    id: number
    createdAt: Date
    updatedAt: Date
    title: string
    authorId: number
}

type UserWithPosts = User & {posts: Post[]}

const prisma = new PrismaClient()

async function getUserWithPosts(userId: number) : Promise<UserWithPosts> {
    let user = await prisma.user.findUnique({
        where: {
            id: userId,
        },
        include: {
            posts: true
        }
    })
    return user;
}
```

This way, you should be able to get rid of Prisma altogether and replace it with an ORM of your choice. One notable drawback is this approach increases the maintenance burden upon changes to the Prisma schema as you need to manually maintain the types.

##### Workaround 2: Generate types using Prisma

You could keep Prisma in your codebase simply to generate the `@prisma/client` and use it for your types. This is possible with the `Prisma.validator` type that is exposed  by the `@prisma/client`. Code snippet to demonstrate this for the exact same function:

```js
// 1: Define the validator
const userWithPosts = Prisma.validator<Prisma.UserArgs>()({
    include: { posts: true },
})

// 2: This type will include a user and all their posts
type UserWithPosts = Prisma.UserGetPayload<typeof userWithPosts>

// function is same as before
async function getUserWithPosts(userId: number): Promise<UserWithPosts>  {
    let user = await prisma.user.findUnique({
        where: {
            id: userId,
        },
        include: {
            posts: true
        }
    })
    return user;
}
```

Additionally, you can always keep the Prisma types updated to your current database state using the [Introspect](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/introspection) feature. This will work even for changes you have made with other ORMS/Query Builders/SQL.

If you want more details, a lot of what I've mentioned here is touched opon in the [Operating against partial structures of your model types](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/advanced-type-safety/operating-against-partial-structures-of-model-types#problem-getting-access-to-the-return-type-of-a-function) concept guide in the Prisma Docs.

Finally, if this dosen't solve your problem, I would request that you open a [new issue](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/new/choose) with the problem and your use case. This really helps us to track and prioritize problems that people are facing.